# how to escape variables for graphql query

Tags: angular, escaping, graphql, apollo

I use angular 6 to write my website with Apollo for interaction with graphpl server. I'd like to be able to escape parameters that I get from the client before adding them to my `gql` query.

this is  my service file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Apollo} from 'apollo-angular';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) { }

  searchForProduct(productName: string) {
    return this.apollo.watchQuery<any>({
    query: gql`{products_by_p_name_search(lang_id:1,query:"${productName}")
    {category_id,price,category_name,id,name,desc,quantity,year_manufacture,image_file}}`
    });
  }

}
```

as you see here the function `searchForProduct` is receiving a `productName` parameter that I add to my `gql` query. how do I escape it properly so the query won't be broken if it contains special chars ?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In GraphQL your queries should be static, that means the query string should not change at runtime *(I wish there was more best practice sharing out there, sorry about that)*. To achieve that GraphQL comes with support for variables. Variables are defined inside of the query string and then send to the server in a different property.

Example for your query:

```
query getProducts($productName: String!) {
  products_by_p_name_search(lang_id:1,query: $productName) {
    category_id
    price
    category_name
    id
    name
    desc
    quantity
    year_manufacture
    image_file
  }
}
```

Then add the variables to your client call:

```
return this.apollo.watchQuery<any>({
  query, //...
  variables: { productName }
});
```

This way there is no escaping for GraphQL (!) needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use template literals in js es6.

In example:

```
const singleProduct = product.id;

  const queryProduct = `{
    product(id:
      "${singleProduct}") {
          variants(first: 15) {
            edges {
              node {
                id,
                title
              }
            }
          }
    }
  }`;
```

Comment: this is not safe, I am using this and I its not working, the query changes when a special character's received